# Display all .txt files inside named top level sub-directories of a base directory

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

I have a base folder, `C:\Users\user\Desktop\BatchTesting\FTP`, which has multiple folders inside. I need to access lets say, 5 folders inside the FTP folder and echo the names of the files inside them.

I have written the following code snippet but sadly it doesn't display the list of files:

```
@echo off
set codeList=Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5
set source=C:\Users\user\Desktop\BatchTesting\FTP\

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%g in (%codeList%) do (

    for /R %source%%%g %%f in (*.txt) do (
        echo %%f
    )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Doublequotes are important I would suggest you use `"%source%%%g"` and the recommended way to set a variable is, `Set "var=value"`. Also you don't need to enable delayed expansion as it isn't needed for what you've posted. If you're having issues, change `off` to `on` on line `1` and add an new last line, `Pause`. When you run the script you should see the commands and any errors or omissions so you can copy them into your question for further support.

Comment: Hey,  I tried all that you have mentioned above, but still I am not getting any output.

Comment: There has to be output, and until you've either assessed it yourself or posted it as an [edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48242895/edit), we cannot hep you!

Comment: Please review [Ask] and [MCVE]. @Comp is correct, you need to show us some results or it'd difficult to workout why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

This simple batch file could be used:

```
@echo off
pushd "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\BatchTesting\FTP"
dir "Test1\*.txt" "Test2\*.txt" "Test3\*.txt" "Test4\*.txt" "Test5\*.txt" /A-D /B /S
popd
```

Or the command **DIR** is executed from within a command prompt window with:

```
dir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\BatchTesting\FTP\Test1\*.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\BatchTesting\FTP\Test2\*.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\BatchTesting\FTP\Test3\*.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\BatchTesting\FTP\Test4\*.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\BatchTesting\FTP\Test5\*.txt" /A-D /B /S
```

The command **DIR** outputs

- for all files (including hidden files) because of `/A-D` (attribute NOT directory)
- matching the wildcard pattern `*.txt`
- the file name + extension because of `/B` (bare format)
- in the five specified directories and all their subdirectories and with full path because of `/S` (search also in subdirectories resulting in also printing full file path).

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`

Answer (score 0):

With echo off, your script produced the following output (after changing source to match my test directory structure):

```
>set codeList=Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5

>set source=d:\Tmp\Test

>setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

>for %g in (Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5) do (for /R d:\Tmp\Test%g %f in (*.txt) do (echo %f ) )

>(for /R d:\Tmp\Test%g %f in (*.txt) do (echo %f ) )

>(for /R d:\Tmp\Test%g %f in (*.txt) do (echo %f ) )

>(for /R d:\Tmp\Test%g %f in (*.txt) do (echo %f ) )

>(for /R d:\Tmp\Test%g %f in (*.txt) do (echo %f ) )

>(for /R d:\Tmp\Test%g %f in (*.txt) do (echo %f ) )

>endlocal
```

Not terribly enlightening and there's no easy way to insert diagnostics. Rearranging your code for easier diagnostics:

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
@set prompt=$G
@set _codeList=Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5
@set _source=d:\Tmp\Test\

@for %%g in (%_codeList%) do @call :Recurse %_source%%%g
@exit /b 0

:Recurse
@for /R %1 %%f in (*.txt) do @call :List %%f
@REM @for /f %%f in ('dir /B /S %1\*.txt') do @call :List %%f
@exit /b 0

:List
@echo %%1 == %1
@exit /b 0
```

And that just happened to work when _source pointed to the correct test directory that was populated with some actual files.  This is an example of how doing your due diligence when posting an SO question, often saves you the trouble of having to post it.

You should avoid using multi-line for loop bodies. The problems you can create for yourself are too numerous to enumerate here. Always calling a subroutine to do the work, makes it much easier to debug.  Using the `@<cmd>` form rather than the blunt echo on/off, also makes it easier to selectively trace through your script and see how replacement variables are being expanded.  The Recurse subroutine shows two different ways to iterate over the files of interest.

I also adopted the habit of prefixing local variables with an underscore.  This way when a script crashes and leaves trash in my environment, I can view the scripts variables alone, with a simple `set _` and I can clean them out with `for /f "tokens=1 delims==" %f in ('set _') do set %f=`.